# Why isn't my Python program running, windows keep closing on me

Tags: python-3.7

I'm new to the Python community, so please be gentle and explain concepts and details slowly until I am able to grasp them.

I'm following the code examples in my book, using Python IDLE and Sublime Text 3 as my editors. When, I am ready to test my work using Python IDLE, Python or Sublime Text 3 the following happens:

1. Either the Python window runs the program quickly and closes out. (Python)
2. I input a value and it hangs there (Python IDLE and Sublime Text 3)

Yet, when I do:

```py
print("Hello")
```

I have no issues.

What am I missing or not doing correctly, so when I start testing my scripts, I don't keep running into the same issues listed above.

I have uninstalled Python and Sublime Text 3 and reinstalled still getting the same results.

I didn't create this, this is one of the examples from the book that I am reading that is not producing an output

```py
def main () :
    celsius = eval(input ("What is the Celsius temperature? "))
    fahrenheit = 9 / 5 * celsius + 32
    print ("The temperature is", fahrenheit, "degrees Fahrenheit.")
main ()
```

I'm expecting to see when I input a value in Celsius a Fahrenheit value to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your program, I think you need to make sure that the input you are taking is of type int. Also eval() is not needed.

Try this,

```
celsius = input ("What is the Celsius temperature? ")
fahrenheit = ((9 / 5) * int(celsius)) + 32
print ("The temperature is", fahrenheit, "degrees Fahrenheit.")
```

[Here](https://repl.it/repls/JampackedIllegalInitializationfile) is a link to try it out (give it 5 seconds to load).

Comment: I have no idea what you just said means. Right, now since I am still learning Python, I will go by what the book says. At the moment, I'm not too concerned with the script itself. My goal is to get any script I create to run without hanging or closing out on me.

Comment: . I ran your version of the script using the link provided it ran like I thought it would. Yet we are still back to square 1, running the script on the programs on my computer.